# How can I know the reason why I can't submit iPhone app to app store?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am trying to publish an app to app store for many times already. After I upload the app through xCode, which it says the upload is successful, I can see my uploaded build from App Store Connect > Activities. It says my build is processing. But after a short while, my build disappears. Then I cannot select my build.

Does anyone have such experience? How can I know what wrong? I really cannot see any place showing the reasons of failure.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is because in your project info.plist you have not assign the permission key properly or not entered and give the valid string of using in your app . So , cross check all the key or your app info.plist.

Comment: Thank you. But is there any way I can know what the problem is? Error msg?

Comment: No you need to be specific for all your permissions. I also faced this issue. And with changes all done i just forget to input one pers mission. So i figured out and again uploaded to app store.

Answer (score 0):

When you upload your app to App Store Connect, app enters a 'processing' state. After it is finished being processed, it either shows in Activity as a new build or it disappears from App Store Connect. The reason can't be seen inside App Store Connect but you do get an email on the email address that you used for authentication (Your apple developer id email address). It states the reason why your app doesn't appear, it usually has something to do with missing permissions.

tl;dr: Check your apple developer account email address.